# Problem with ion-searchbar height and placeholder

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, searchbar

I hope you are all well.

I have a problem with **Ionic 5 - Angular** , Searchbar.

I added the **searchbar** like this :

```
<ion-searchbar
          [(ngModel)]="text"
          (ionChange)="search()"
          placeholder="Search for cars"
          class="searchbarInput"
        ></ion-searchbar>
```

I am trying to change the height of the searchbar to have 48px and also the placeholder text to have 10px , but with no success.

I also tried to customize the class in the inspected element like search-input and also  search-input-container with no success.

When i customize the css in Inspect Elements and add there styles it works but in my scss its not working.

I would really appreciate if someone can help me to solve this issue.

Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Ionic has changed the way to update the styles, they now use variables to apply styling, you would need to override those variables.

Comment: For some reason, the other attributes work fine. For example, the width. When I tried height it seems to work like margin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<ion-searchbar>` seems to work like this: `<div><ion-input></ion-input></div>`, so the height attribute affects the `div` element .You can try `height:fit-content` or `max-content`.